# Vector drawables not properly displayed on some devices

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I just replaced png drawables in my app with vector drawables and this seems to work fine on most devices, but for some reasons I experience some weird display on some random icons on a Samsung S8 running Android 8.
Some icons are displayed with the outline kind of pixelated and I have no clue why as I tested the exact same APK one maybe 10 other device without any issue.

For example with the following layout, the first icon (previous track) has this issue, but none if the other ones
If I change the vector drawable for this icon it still shows the issue.
Any idea what could be causing this?

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/streamControlsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/previousTrack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/previousTrackButtonContentDescription"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/previous_track_button" >
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/rewind"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/fastRewindTrackButtonContentDescription"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/rewind_button" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/playPauseButtonContentDescription"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/play_button" >
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fastForward"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/fastForwardButtonContentDescription"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fast_forward" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nextTrack"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nextTrackButtonContentDescription"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/next_track_button" >
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Example of the issue

[image]